# How to use document.querySelectorAll where the class name is bound to a property (:class="")?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, dom, binding

I have a for loop:

```
<div v-for="chart in allCharts" :key="chart.id">
     <div :class="chart.eContainer"></div>
</div>
```

This creates a new div, each with a different class name for each chart.

I have the following method which creates the container for each chart displayed on the page:

```
    createChartContainer(chartRef) {
        var eChart = chartRef.chartElement;
        var eParent = document.querySelector('.projectEditChart');
        eParent.appendChild(eChart);
    },
```

How can I alter the method such that every value of chart.eContainer in the for loop above goes into where projectEditChart is?

So as an example, if chart.eContainer = asdfghj for one chart, then for another chart.eContainer = wertgfegt. Then, how can I dynamically alter where projectEditChart is so that it loops through all values of chart.eContainer?

Something like the following:

```
for(chart in allCharts) {
    var eChart = chartRef.chartElement;
    var eParent = document.querySelector(.chart.eContainer);   (THIS IS DEFINITELY WRONG BUT LOGICALLY THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO - select all the class names that have values equal to chart.eContainer)
    eParent.appendChild(eChart);
}
```

i.e. How can I create a new chart container for every chart? (var eChart, var eParent and eParent.appendChild(eChart); are essential)

Comment: When using Vue, you shouldn't be manipulating the DOM. Let your data drive the template

Comment: That is a better idea, but how would I be able to create a new chart container for every chart using the createChartContainer in that case?

Comment: There's not enough information here. What calls `createChartContainer`? What is `chartRef` that is passed in to it?